# How can I decrease brush opacity gradually as I paint a stroke?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

I want to gradually change the opacity of a brush as I perform a stroke.  How can I modify the brush presets to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brush Panel > Transfer > Set the Opacity Jitter Control to `Fade`. Then adjust the field to the right and the "minimum" slider until you are happy.

[image]